# Insert data in Laravel - IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: php, laravel

I got problem when i try to insert data on database sqlserver.

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'XWEB_ANNOUNCE' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. (SQL: insert into [XWEB_ANNOUNCE] ([id], [status], [date], [title]) values (1, 1, 12/31/2022 12:00 AM, New Year))
```

I use updateOrCreate method and i use eloquent model. I want to find solution with eloquent if it possible.
This is my code -

```
public function do_adminannounce(Request $request)
    {

        ANNOUNCE::updateOrCreate(
            ['id' => 1],
            ['status' => $request->status, 'date' => $request->date, 'title' => $request->title]);
        return redirect('adminpanel/announce');
    }
```

Comment: you can't set a value to the 'id' field apparently ...

Comment: @lagbox I dont try to set a value to 'id'.

Comment: yes you are ... that is how `updateOrCreate` works ... it tries to find a record by the first array, if it can't a new model with the attributes from the first array is then filled with the second array and saved ... so you are setting a value to 'id', just as the INSERT query in the error is showing

Comment: @lagbox and how i can make when i dont have row to create and when have row only to update it?
This method (updateOrCreate) work in MySQL but with MSSQL dont work...